# Real Time Updating winforms visual studio 2010 .net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, entity-framework

I am having some problems getting the data to reload after its updated to the database i am loading my gridview from form load   BindGrid() event I have included my code here.

My Delcarations are as follows I have tried everything here but cant force it to refresh the grid

```
  Dim dbContext As New R3Delivery
   Dim threeContext As New skechersDeliveryEntities1
   Dim bs As New BindingSource


   Private Sub frmConfirmDeliverys_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        BindGrid()
        dgDeliverys.Columns(0).ReadOnly = True
        dgDeliverys.Columns(1).ReadOnly = True
        dgDeliverys.Columns(2).ReadOnly = True

    End Sub
    Public Sub BindGrid()
        Dim cfglocation As Int16
        cfglocation = cfb.StoreLocation

        bs.DataSource = (From u In threeContext.R3Delivery Where u.isprocessed = True AndAlso u.location = 1
                          Select u)


        bs.ResetBindings(True)
        dgDeliverys.DataSource = bs
    End Sub
```

My save button is as follows

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
       threeContext.SaveChanges()

    BindGrid()
End Sub
```

I thought I should show my declaration of my form as well the above code is in my edit form the below is my calling from

```
Dim frmConfirmDeliverys As New frmConfirmDeliverys
    frmConfirmDeliverys.ShowInTaskbar = False

    frmConfirmDeliverys.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: thank you whoever gave me the five votes ;-)

Comment: The first thing to do would be to debug your code and check whether your query actually retrieves the data that you think it should.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing this?

```
dgDeliverys.Datasource=Nothing
dgDeliverys.DataSource = bs
```

or

```
dgDeliverys.Refresh
```

Also like  *jmcilhinney* said, check if the data you are expecting is returned by the query.